# update PDO não me esta a fazer os update

Tags: php

estou com problema ao fazer um update
que não me esta a funcionar estou a usar PDO. as consultas funciona na prefeição.

codigo que tenho no script que recebe os dados do formulario

```
<script>
    function update() {
        var data = {"func": "save"};
        data = $("#editar").serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);          
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "../Logica/info/info.php",
            data: data,
            success: function () {
                alert("dados modificados com sucesso");
            }
        });        
    } ;
</script>
```

codigo php

```
$id= filter_input(INPUT_POST,'ID');
$observacoes= filter_input(INPUT_POST,'observacoes');
if (isset($_POST["func"]) && !empty($_POST["func"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $_POST["func"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
        case "save": editar($id,$observacoes);
        break;
    }
}

function editar($id,$observacoes){
    $db = new ligacao();
    $conn = $db->open();
    $sql = "UPDATE INFO
    SET OBS =$observacoes
    WHERE id=$id";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

nao me esta a fazer o update

Comment: Ao executar no php, `print_r($_POST)` aparece a chave `func`?

Comment: sim aparece acho que já descobri... nao estava a receber o id...porque antes tenho um formulario mas esse id não estava lá porque ningem pode saber ...vou te rque usar uma variavel de sessão... ja digo se deu ou não

Comment: no formulario criei um input escondido para guardar o id que vou buscar a bd antes, tenho um select e coloco a informação num form.

Comment: Isso resolveu o problema?

Comment: sim resolveu o problema..não estava a guardar o id logo nunca seria enviado ao servidor sql

Answer (score 0):

Utilize prepared statements e faça o tratamente do erro caso ocorra, verificando o retorno de `execute()`, campos do tipo texto e variantes devem estar entre aspas simples ao fazer uma consulta no banco de dados, ao utilizar prepared statements não é necessario se preocupar com isso.

```
function editar($id,$observacoes){
    $db = new ligacao();
    $conn = $db->open();
    $sql = "UPDATE INFO SET OBS = ? WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if(!$stmt->execute(array($observacoes, $id))){
        echo'Erro:<pre>';
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Modifique o javascript para saber se ocorreu algum erro no PHP.

```
success: function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   alert("dados modificados com sucesso");
}
```